# Can I include varying numbers of tables in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am investigating using SSRS for a reporting need.  I have a collection of tables I'd like to include in the report.  The number of tables in this collection can change everyday and is effectively random.  Am I able to do this in SSRS?

There's the list control that can contain a varying number of elements, but it appears to work on rows, not tables.

If I'm able to do this, can I control pagination in a PDF export?  the tables are of a size that I'll need either 2 or 3 tables per printed page.

---

What I'm doing now is I have several reports I generate in C# using [Excel Com calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29).  My code generates both Excel files and PDF files.  The reports contain mostly a random number of tables, with some charts as well.  I have to perform calculations on all of my data, I can't simply pull data from my database.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with a List control, that's going to be more or less your only means of having a "dynamic" number of tables.  The list control *can* contain another table.  The caveat here is that your List control needs to group on something, so that the data contained in each child table would be a "group" of data.  Here's an example of a list control holding a table; ignore the silly data, it's leftover from another question.  In this example, the list control is grouping on the "Question" field, so each row in the list contains a table, which contains all of the detail level records for a question.

[image]

Comment: I would need to apply formatting to these tables that may be too much.  Alternating row colors.  The first column, or last row a different color.  Different number formats for different rows in the same table.  Do you know if this kind of formatting is supported by SSRS?  I'm thinking it may be too much.

Comment: The only one of those things you listed that might be a challenge is different number formats for different rows within the same table - even then, you should be able to accomplish that, though you'll likely be writing a pretty nasty Expression to make it happen.